# Chaining the map state with choice state in AWS Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

In AWS Step Functions, we have a use case where depending on the value of each item in the ItemsPath, we would like to trigger a different choice of task.

Consider the scenario where ItemsPath has the following:

```
[
 {"type":"A", "index":"0"},
 {"type":"B", "index":"1"}
]
```

For type "A" I would want to trigger a lambda of arn "lambda-A", and for type "B" we want to trigger a lambda of arn "lambda-B".

Comment: Are you trying to loop invoking Lambda functions with ItemsPath in one Stepfunctions flow? Or one Lambda function in one flow?

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you can have a map state with a choice state inside which splits the work for A and B as follows:

```
{
    "Type": "Choice",
    "Choices": [
        {
            "Variable": "$.type",
            "StringEquals": "A",
            "Next": "Go_to_LambdaA_state"
        }
    ],
    "Default": "Go_to_LambdaB_state"
}
```